Is it correct to think that people during Noah's day had never seen rain, based on Genesis 2:4-6?
First, in Genesis 2, we learn the history of the earth.  God had not cause it to rain, but also that there was no man to till the ground:
Genesis 2:4-6

4 This is the history of the heavens and the earth when they were
created, in the day that the Lord God made the earth and the heavens,
5 before any plant of the field was in the earth and before any herb
of the field had grown. For the Lord God had not caused it to rain on
the earth, and there was no man to till the ground; 6 but a mist went
up from the earth and watered the whole face of the ground.

Then, after the fall of man, God sent Adam out to till the ground, and told Cain that when he tilled, the ground would no longer yield its strength.
Genesis 3:23

Therefore the LORD God sent him out of the garden of Eden to till the
ground from which he was taken.

Genesis 4:12

“When you till the ground, it shall no longer yield its strength to
you. A fugitive and a vagabond you shall be on the earth.”

Therefore, we cannot say that only one of the conditions in Genesis 2:5-6 remain and not the other, rain and till.  Is this correct?

Correct.  I agree.  But what are you really asking?

Thank you for your response. I asked because I was told I am wrong and wonder if I am wrong.

Answer
People during Noah’s day had seen rain based on Genesis 1:14:
Explanation

“And God said, Let luminaries be in the expanse of the heavens, to
divide between the day and the night. And let them be for signs and
for seasons, and for days and years” (Gen 1:14).

How seasons can be seasons without summer and winter with its rains? How years can be years without seasons?
These things have been going on in cycles even during the time of Noah. For God says after the Flood:
“While the earth remains, seedtime and harvest, cold and heat, summer and winter, and day and night shall not cease” (Gen 8:22).
If something has to cease or not to cease, it has to be going on in the first place. The Hebrew word used here for “cease” is related to Sabbath. So people are commanded to rest (cease from work) after six days of work; not before work.
Similarly, the seasons will never cease because they were going on always.

“For, behold, the winter has passed, the rain has passed, it
goes to itself” (Song of Solomon 2:11).


“And they do not say in their heart, Let us now fear Jehovah our God
who gives both the former and the latter rain in its season”
(Jer 5:24).

Winter involves two rains in the Mediterranean climate where most of the Biblical events took place.
Conclusion
God provided for the due seasons in the creation itself (Gen 1:14). Seasons mean winter and summer that never ceased even during Noah’s time except during the Flood (Gen 8:22). Winter involved the former rain and the latter rain in the Mediterranean Basin.

No, it is not necessarily correct to think that the people of Noah's time had never seen rain. The "mist" of Gen. 2 refers to the time "before any plant of the field was in the earth and before any herb of the field had grown." The text does not indicate how long this mist lasted. It may even describe evaporation that became rain relatively soon.  So the cycle of evaporation from the lakes and oceans, followed by rain to replenish the earth, may have been part of God's original plan of creation.
An argument against this idea is that there were many rivers in the territory surrounding Eden, so crops could have been raised by irrigation. However, this contradicts the scientific outlook that without rain, rivers would run dry; and there is no indication that the mist of Gen. 2 continued beyond Adam and Eve's time in the Garden. Moreover, the text of Gen. 4 describes the emergence of cities, agriculture, animal husbandry, metallurgy and other foundations of civilization that are hard to imagine existing on the basis of the Edenic mist without rain.

17 And Cain knew his wife; and she conceived, and bare Enoch: and he builded a city, and called the name of the city after the name of his son, Enoch....
20 And Adah bare Jabal: he was the father of such as dwell in tents,
and of such as have cattle.
22 And Zillah, she also bare Tubalcain, an instructer of every
artificer in brass and iron.

Conclusion: the text can be read either way. However there is nothing in the text that precludes God using rain rather than mist to water the land from just after the time that the first couple was expelled from Eden, if not before.

You wrote, "However, this contradicts the scientific outlook that without rain, rivers would run dry . . ." This is not true. Water from springs can be sufficient to create rivers. Consider the following. Currently, geological researchers and theorists believe that there is perhaps three times as much water inside the earth than on the surface of the earth! This water is more than sufficient to fill the rivers of the earth, not to mention the oceans themselves!
https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn25723-massive-ocean-discovered-towards-earths-core/

@Dieter - I think you're mistaken, the deep water you're talking about is not generally connected to ground water. Ground water that powers springs does typically come from rain which has then filtered through the earth into subsurface reservoirs. So when I take a drink of Scottish Highland spring water, it's actually rain water from hundreds or thousands of years ago that has just taken the long way around. :)

Yes, possibly. But fossil water aquifer systems are the subject of a lot of continuing research over the past 50 years. See https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1671341 I don't think anyone can exclude any possibilities at this point. In fact, the author of original article that I linked to includes the following quote: “It’s good evidence the Earth’s water came from within,” says Steven Jacobsen of Northwestern University in Evanston, Illinois. The hidden water could also act as a buffer for the oceans on the surface, explaining why they have stayed the same size for millions of years."
